# C#: only one typecast in linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a gridview and each row displays one instance of `MyCustomType`. The instance itself is stored in the `Tag` property of DataGridViewRow. Now I want to use linq to select certain rows, based on multiple criteria. This looks like this:

```
var rows = grid_series.Rows
    .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Where(x => ((MyCustomType)x).myProperty != string.Empty)
    .Where(x => ((MyCustomType)x).myOtherProperty < 42);
```

But I really want to avoid to cast the `Tag`-object in every single `where` statement. Is there a way to cast the object only once and use repeatedly? I thought about using a select statement first. Then I do have to apply the cast only once, but then I'd have to "re-convert" each result back to `DataGridViewRow` which I don't think is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about selecting the `Tag` and do another `Cast` (or `OfType<>` of not all the rows contains  `MyCustomType`) afterwards:

```
var rows = grid_series.Rows
    .Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select(r => r.Tag).Cast<MyCustomType>()
    .Where(x => x.myProperty != string.Empty)
    .Where(x => x.myOtherProperty < 42);
```

If you want `IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow>` you you can try:

```
var rows = grid_series.Rows
    .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Select(r => new { MyType = (MyCustomType)r.Tag, Row = r })
    .Where(x => x.MyType.myProperty != string.Empty)
    .Where(x => x.MyType.myOtherProperty < 42)
    .Select(x => x.Row);
```

Comment: But what is the resulting type? I need to have an IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow>. This looks as if I would get an IEnumerable<MyCustomType>. Am I right?

Comment: If you want `IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow>` probably your solution is better, but I will update my answer.